# R list of intersection of lists

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose you are handed the following dataframe  reuslting of the following steps:

```
df= data.frame(id1= c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2), name =c("a","a","b","b","c","a","a","d","d","b"), name2 = c(NA,NA,"a",NA,"c",   "d","a","b",NA,NA))
df = df %>% group_by(id1) %>% summarise(name =name %>% unique %>% toString, name2= name2%>% unique %>% toString) 
df = as.data.frame(df)
df = df %>%mutate(name = strsplit(name, ", "), name2 = strsplit(name2, ", "))
```

The resulting `df` is to be used to create a new column, where row by row gets the intersection of `name` and `name2`, where within each row, I do not care about the order of elements in `name` and `name2`

**Here is what I tried**, it only gets me the first element however

```
library(purrr)
inter = rep("", length(df$name))
for (row in c(1:length(df$name)))  {
    print(row)
    inter[[row]] = ifelse(purrr::is_empty(intersect(df$name[[row]],df$name2[[row]])),
                    NA,intersect(df$name[[row]],df$name2[[row]]))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is `map2` to loop over the corresponding `list`s ('name', 'name2') and get the `intersect`ion of elements in a new `list` column

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    mutate(newCol = map2(name, name2, intersect))
```

Comment: and there I was thinking there is no non-native-R way to do this! very elegant, thanks!

Comment: @SAFEX  If you meant `base R`, the option is `df$newCol <- Map(intersect, df$name, df$name2)`

Comment: yes that is what I meant. Is there also a way to count the number of elents in each intersection as a new variable without looping?

Comment: Try `df %>% mutate(new = map2(name, name2, intersect), len = lengths(new))`  It is a `list` of vectors, so we need some functions to loop over the list to get the intersect